# base_url() is not acessible in footer.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I include two files in every view, which are `nav.php` and `footer.php`.
All session varaiables and `base_url()` are working in `nav.php` file, but when I want do the same in `footer.php` it is not working.

`url` helper file is autoload via `config/autoload.php` as

> $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');

I spent whole day to figure it out my self but it's not working.

**nav.php**

```
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('projects/new_project'); ?>">Post New Project</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('projects'); ?>">All Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('projects?t=featured'); ?>">Featured Projects</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Funds <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('funds/upload'); ?>">Upload Funds</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('funds/withdrow'); ?>">Withdraw Funds</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**footer.php**

```
            <ul class="footer-list">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('users/login'); ?>">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('users/Register'); ?>">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
```

In my viewname.php file I'm calling them as

```
        <?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>
        Other code here
        <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

`nav.php` working fine but `footer.php` not working.

**autoload.php**

```
(Line :67) $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

**config.php**

```
(Line :17) $config['base_url']  = 'http://localhost/cl';
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't enough info to be able to offer suggestions from. Can you be more specific of the issues you face and what you've already tried? (If you went to a car mechanic and said "My car doesn't work", what would you expect them to do?)

Comment: are you getting empty result for base_url()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably an echo is missing?

And make sure that autoload is not declared more than once.

In order to use base_url(), you must first have the URL Helper loaded (which you have done). This can be done either in application/config/autoload.php (on or around line 67):

> $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Or, manually:

> $this->load->helper('url');

Once it's loaded, be sure to keep in mind that base_url() **doesn't implicitly print or echo** out anything, rather it returns the value to be printed:

> echo base_url();

Remember also that **the value returned is the site's base url as provided in the config file**. CodeIgniter will accomodate an empty value in the config file as well:

> If this (base_url) is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the
>   protocol, domain and path to your installation.
>   application/config/config.php, line 13

EDIT:
Change the following

> include('includes/nav.php'); // Other code here
>   include('includes/footer.php');

to

```
$this->load->view('includes/nav.php'); 
// Other code here 
$this->load->view('includes/footer.php');
```

I wouldn’t use this method in an MVC framework since there is no need with $this->load->view. Another thing is the paths have to be absolute/relative which mean if you did change the folder structure you have to go update all include statements. Its really against MVC structure. If we there is ability to do this using parser or defined methods then why we call view in another view:)

Comment: Use $this->load->view instead of include... updated my answer

Comment: why you removed your comment, actually it did the trick, problem was that I included files from outside the directory of application.